# How to add an information display button to the interactive plot toolbar

Tags: python, matplotlib, user-interface, toolbar

The matplotlib plot toolbar has some support for [customization](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/user_interfaces/toolmanager_sgskip.html). This example is provided on the official documentation:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backend_tools import ToolBase, ToolToggleBase


plt.rcParams['toolbar'] = 'toolmanager'


class ListTools(ToolBase):
    """List all the tools controlled by the `ToolManager`."""
    default_keymap = 'm'  # keyboard shortcut
    description = 'List Tools'

    def trigger(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('_' * 80)
        fmt_tool = "{:12} {:45} {}".format
        print(fmt_tool('Name (id)', 'Tool description', 'Keymap'))
        print('-' * 80)
        tools = self.toolmanager.tools
        for name in sorted(tools):
            if not tools[name].description:
                continue
            keys = ', '.join(sorted(self.toolmanager.get_tool_keymap(name)))
            print(fmt_tool(name, tools[name].description, keys))
        print('_' * 80)
        fmt_active_toggle = "{0!s:12} {1!s:45}".format
        print("Active Toggle tools")
        print(fmt_active_toggle("Group", "Active"))
        print('-' * 80)
        for group, active in self.toolmanager.active_toggle.items():
            print(fmt_active_toggle(group, active))


class GroupHideTool(ToolToggleBase):
    """Show lines with a given gid."""
    default_keymap = 'S'
    description = 'Show by gid'
    default_toggled = True

    def __init__(self, *args, gid, **kwargs):
        self.gid = gid
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def enable(self, *args):
        self.set_lines_visibility(True)

    def disable(self, *args):
        self.set_lines_visibility(False)

    def set_lines_visibility(self, state):
        for ax in self.figure.get_axes():
            for line in ax.get_lines():
                if line.get_gid() == self.gid:
                    line.set_visible(state)
        self.figure.canvas.draw()


fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot([1, 2, 3], gid='mygroup')
plt.plot([2, 3, 4], gid='unknown')
plt.plot([3, 2, 1], gid='mygroup')

# Add the custom tools that we created
fig.canvas.manager.toolmanager.add_tool('List', ListTools)
fig.canvas.manager.toolmanager.add_tool('Show', GroupHideTool, gid='mygroup')

# Add an existing tool to new group `foo`.
# It can be added as many times as we want
fig.canvas.manager.toolbar.add_tool('zoom', 'foo')

# Remove the forward button
fig.canvas.manager.toolmanager.remove_tool('forward')

# To add a custom tool to the toolbar at specific location inside
# the navigation group
fig.canvas.manager.toolbar.add_tool('Show', 'navigation', 1)

plt.show()
```

Which opens this plot where you can hide/show some data:

[image: ![enter image description here]

**How can I add such a button to display some text (regarding the plot data) on a new window?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could modify the example you provided from the matplotlib documentation to add a button that create a figure in a new window with only text in it. And, once you click on the same button again it closes the window.

See code below, I called the implemented tool/button 'Info':

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backend_tools import ToolBase, ToolToggleBase

plt.rcParams['toolbar'] = 'toolmanager'

class ListTools(ToolBase):
    """List all the tools controlled by the `ToolManager`."""
    default_keymap = 'm'  # keyboard shortcut
    description = 'List Tools'

    def trigger(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('_' * 80)
        fmt_tool = "{:12} {:45} {}".format
        print(fmt_tool('Name (id)', 'Tool description', 'Keymap'))
        print('-' * 80)
        tools = self.toolmanager.tools
        for name in sorted(tools):
            if not tools[name].description:
                continue
            keys = ', '.join(sorted(self.toolmanager.get_tool_keymap(name)))
            print(fmt_tool(name, tools[name].description, keys))
        print('_' * 80)
        fmt_active_toggle = "{0!s:12} {1!s:45}".format
        print("Active Toggle tools")
        print(fmt_active_toggle("Group", "Active"))
        print('-' * 80)
        for group, active in self.toolmanager.active_toggle.items():
            print(fmt_active_toggle(group, active))


class GroupHideTool(ToolToggleBase):
    """Show lines with a given gid."""
    default_keymap = 'S'
    description = 'Show by gid'
    default_toggled = True
    
    def __init__(self, *args, gid, **kwargs):
        self.gid = gid
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def enable(self, *args):
        self.set_lines_visibility(True)

    def disable(self, *args):
        self.set_lines_visibility(False)

    def set_lines_visibility(self, state):
        for ax in self.figure.get_axes():
            for line in ax.get_lines():
                if line.get_gid() == self.gid:
                    line.set_visible(state)
        self.figure.canvas.draw()

class ShowInfoTool(ToolToggleBase):
    """Show lines with a given gid."""
    default_keymap = 'I'
    description = 'Show info'
    default_toggled = False

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def enable(self,*args):
        fig=plt.figure()
        plt.box(False)
        plt.xticks([])
        plt.yticks([])
        
        plt.text(0.5,0.5,'Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error\n sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam\n eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi\n architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo.' ,fontsize=10,ha='center',va='center')
        plt.show()

    def disable(self, *args):
        plt.close()

fig=plt.figure()
plt.plot([1, 2, 3], gid='mygroup')
plt.plot([2, 3, 4], gid='unknown')
plt.plot([3, 2, 1], gid='mygroup')

# Add the custom tools that we created
fig.canvas.manager.toolmanager.add_tool('List', ListTools)
fig.canvas.manager.toolmanager.add_tool('Show', GroupHideTool, gid='mygroup')
fig.canvas.manager.toolmanager.add_tool('Info', ShowInfoTool)

# Add an existing tool to new group `foo`.
# It can be added as many times as we want
fig.canvas.manager.toolbar.add_tool('zoom', 'foo')

# Remove the forward button
fig.canvas.manager.toolmanager.remove_tool('forward')

# To add a custom tool to the toolbar at specific location inside
# the navigation group
fig.canvas.manager.toolbar.add_tool('Show', 'navigation', 1)
fig.canvas.manager.toolbar.add_tool('Info', 'navigation', 2)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Hello @jylls. Thank you very much for your reply. This is the only option? Making a blank plot with text on it?

Comment: There could be other ways to do this. I can't quite see at the moment what else could be done but it doesn't mean there aren't other options...What features are you missing with this current approach?